# In one specific cell have it output to 2 specific cells

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, excel-formula, nested

What I would like to do is use a excel function in one specific cell to output to the cell next to it. So as you can see in the image below I enter =TODAY(). What I would like to do is in cell c4 is used today function to enter todays date in cell 4 and in Cell d4 enter the date 3 days later. So if possible in cell c4 I would enter a function that states todays date in cell c4 and the workday 3 days later.

[image: sheet]

Comment: `=WORKDAY(C4,3)`?

Comment: That would work if I entered in in cell d4 but I want to enter everything in cell c4

Comment: You cannot use a formula in a cell that the user will enter a value.

Comment: And a formula cannot change the value of any cell but the one in which it is placed.

Comment: You would have to write your own custom **User Defined Function (UDF)** to get what you are looking for, and even then it would be very limited and not overly useful

Comment: Are you using a version that supports Dynamic Arrays?  If so, you could write a formula that Spills into the next cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For versions that support [Dynamic Arrays](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531), create a formula that Spills the result you want

Example

```
=WORKDAY(TODAY(),{0,3})
```

[image]

To make the number of days offset variable, use `SEQUENCE` to generate the offsets

```
=WORKDAY(TODAY(),SEQUENCE(1,2,0,D7))
```

[image]

For Non-Dyanamic Array versions, the first formula could also be entered as a array formula (CSE) into `C4:D4`

Comment: Thanks for the answer it was exactly what I was looking for. Say I want to add to what you wrote if have another cell that displays another workday 3 days later from cell d4 in cell e4. So cell c4 would have todays date, d4 would have the workday 3 days later from cell c4 and cell e4 would have the work day three days later from cell d4.

Comment: Just extend the array `{0,3}` to `{0,3,6}`

Answer (score 0):

If you only ever want to use Today() as the starting date, you can use this:

```
=TEXT(TODAY(),"ddd, dd-MM-yyyy")&" - next workday: "&TEXT(WORKDAY(TODAY(),3)," dddd")
```

[image]

If you want the user to enter a date, that entry must be in a different cell, and you need to replace the Today() function in the formula above with that cell reference.